# R Sweave chunk options

Tags: r, sweave

Say I have two chunks of code seen below,

```
<<include=FALSE>>=
inf.col <- cbind(dffits(col.lm), dfbetas(col.lm), cooks.distance(col.lm))
inf.col462 <- data.frame(inf.col[462,])
rownames(inf.col462) <- c("DFFITS", "DBETAS Intercept", "DBETAS Accept", "DBETAS Top10perc", "DBETAS PrivateYes", "DBETAS Outstate", "DBETAS PhD", "Cook's D")
inf.col462
inf.col484 <- data.frame(inf.col[484,])
rownames(inf.col484) <- c("DFFITS", "DBETAS Intercept", "DBETAS Accept", "DBETAS Top10perc", "DBETAS PrivateYes", "DBETAS Outstate", "DBETAS PhD", "Cook's D")
inf.col484
inf.col251 <- data.frame(inf.col[251,])
rownames(inf.col251) <- c("DFFITS", "DBETAS Intercept", "DBETAS Accept", "DBETAS Top10perc", "DBETAS PrivateYes", "DBETAS Outstate", "DBETAS PhD", "Cook's D")
inf.col251
inf.col460 <- data.frame(inf.col[460,])
rownames(inf.col460) <- c("DFFITS", "DBETAS Intercept", "DBETAS Accept", "DBETAS Top10perc", "DBETAS PrivateYes", "DBETAS Outstate", "DBETAS PhD", "Cook's D")
inf.col460
@
```

---

```
<<>>=
inf.col2 <- cbind(inf.col462, inf.col484, inf.col251, inf.col460)
inf.col2
@
```

---

And in my .pdf output I only want to see the code from the second chunk.  But the second chunk utilizes code from the first chunk.  So if I use `<<eval=FALSE>>=`  the code will not run at all and R won't know what the objects inf.col462, etc. even are.  I tried `<<include=FALSE>>=` as shown, but it still prints all of the code from chunk 1.

How can I not print chunk 1, but store it's info in cache to evaluate chunk 2?

Thank you.

P.S. I have required: dplyr, knitr, tidyr.

Comment: Have you tried `echo=FALSE`?

Comment: @ChrisC `echo=FALSE` doesn't display the code, but still displays the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using `<<results=hide>>=`.  It doesn't display the output but still keeps it in memory for later chunks of code.  Thanks!

Comment: I was required to put quotes around the word 'hide'